# Lighttpd appending /main.py/ to url

Tags: python, lighttpd

I have a web server using web.py running on lighttpd.

My lighttpd.conf file is as follows:

```
server.modules = ("mod_fastcgi", "mod_rewrite", "mod_compress", "mod_expire", "mod_redirect")
server.document-root = "/home/smiley/british_detail/code/"
server.name = "britishdetail.co.uk"

$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
  $HTTP["host"] =~ ".*" {
    url.redirect = (".*" => "https://%0$0")
  }
}

$SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
  ssl.engine = "enable"
  ssl.pemfile = "/home/smiley/british_detail/certs/server.pem"
  ssl.ca-file = "/home/smiley/british_detail/certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt"

  mimetype.assign = (
    ".html" => "text/html",
    ".css" => "text/css",
    ".jpg" => "image/jpeg",
    ".png" => "image/png",
    ".js"  => "text/javascript"
  )

  expire.url = (
    "/static" => "access plus 7 days"
  )    

  fastcgi.server = ( "/main.py" =>
  ((
    "socket" => "/tmp/fastcgi.socket",
    "bin-path" => "/home/smiley/british_detail/code/main.py",
    "max-procs" => 1
  ))
  )

  compress.cache-dir = "/tmp/lighttpdcompress/"
  compress.filetype = (
    "text/html",
    "text/css",
    "text/javascript"
  )

  url.rewrite-once = (
    "^/favicon.ico$" => "/static/assets/favicon.ico",
    "^/static/(.*)$" => "/static/$1",
    "^/(.*)$" => "/main.py/$1"
  )
}
```

The problem I have is that when a request is redirected from a http request to a https request /main.py/ appears in the url.
For example:
`http://britishdetail.co.uk => https://britishdetail.co.uk/main.py/`
The site is live if you want to take a look.

How do I prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`url.rewrite(-once)` triggers before `url.redirect`, so don't rewrite if you want to redirect; for example put your main config apart from redirect ("ssl only") in the `$SERVER["socket"] == ":443"` block.

Comment: I have changed my lighttpd conf as per instruction, however I still have the problem. I have edited my question to show the new conf file.

Comment: clear your browser cache, curl output looks fine

Comment: Ahh thank you so much, didn't realise stuff like that got cached!